# Py for Affiliated names in Google Scholar

Tags: python

I am working on a project using the Python library [Scholarly](https://pypi.org/project/scholarly/) to work with Google Scholar.

To get all titles from a given author you can run

```
from scholarly import scholarly
search_query = scholarly.search_author('Steven A Cholewiak')
author = next(search_query).fill()
print(author)
```

Then to get all abstracts from a given author I wrote

```
for i in range(len(author.publications)):
    pub = author.publications[i].fill()
    print(pub)
```

Now, the problem I am specifically working with is that I have a dataset that looks as follows: (but far more rows obviously)

[image]

'title' refers to project title, not of a particular paper. In principle my research goal is to download the papers from each author (referred by 'firstname'+'othernames'+'surname'), which were associated with the project referred by 'title'. One method might be by fuzzy similarity but so far I'm thinking best is to just download all papers of that author with the **correct coauthors**.

So, for each person named in the df above:

1. Obtain a list of projects they worked on
2. For each project, list the other authors working on the same project
3. Download titles/abstracts (from Google Scholar) for papers where those authors all show up together

The first two steps are fine with for-loops, but it's the last I'm not sure how to do--namely how to specify getting the papers (titles/abstracts) only where all those working on the project are named as authors. Any one help?

Comment: Request the papers for each author individually, stored in a set, and then find the intersection of the papers (via title, doi, etc) for the authors you care about. The resulting set would be the papers that were authored by the group of individuals.

Comment: I think the most straightforward way will be to get a list of all projects for each author and then identify any projects that are in every list.